# Pyspark data distribution

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I have 1000 csv files that are to be processed in parallel using map function available in spark. I have two desktops connected in a cluster and I'm using the pyspark shell for computation. I am passing the name of csv files into the map function and the function accesses the files based on name. However, I need to copy files to the slave for the process to function properly. This means there has to be a copy of all the csv files on the other system. Kindly suggest an alternative storage while avoiding data transfer latency.

I also tried storing these files into a 3-d array and generating an RDD by using parallelize command. But that gives out of memory error.

Answer (score 1):

you can use spark-csv to load the files
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Then you can use dataframe concept to pre-process the files.
Since its 1000 csv files and if there is some link among them , use spark-sql to run operation on them , and then extract your output for final computation.

If that doesn't work , you can try to load the same in HBase or Hive and then use spark to compute , I checked with 100 gb of csv contents in my single node cluster.
It may help

Comment: I need each csv file to be available as a separate array for performing some ML functions. I think the way you pointed out is for sql querying functions. Is retaining them in memory possible using spark-csv? How do the slave machines access the data?

Comment: Spark SQL actually query structured data as a distributed dataset (RDD) , so even ML can be run . accessing the data is now same like any other RDD

Comment: It solves that problem, but there's still the issue that the data has to be present on both workers for accessing it using spark-csv. So, there's no way but to use HBase for quicker data access without duplication?

Comment: well where is ur HDFS located as its already distributed access and so does Hbase & Hive. So if we follow that concept ur hdfs can be central & ur data multiple worker can access that data resource..